# Loading Tinybox (on iframe) over parent frame

Tags: javascript, html, popup, modal-dialog

First of all I'd like to thanks in advance for your answers on this.

Currently I'm working on a site where I have a page that contains an `<iframe>`.

The page within the `<iframe>` has the **Tinybox** call to open the modal popup (that I want to overlay over the parent page), but the overlay stays within the `<iframe>`.

Is there a way to load the overlay over the parent page? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Are the pages on the same domain, protocol and port?

Comment: Then place the code that creates the popup in the top window, and call it from inside the iframe using window.top.yourFunction() or parent.yourFunction().

Comment: But then I had no advantage on having this component "externalized" and used on an <iframe>, as I would need to have this part of code (the one that instantiates the popup window) on all pages of my website, with the evident disadvantages in terms of maintenance. I don't want that.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just keep the script in a separate file, and include that on every page?

Comment: @jack: I'll propose that solution to my client, as I don't see any other options so far. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, I'll just keep the script in a separate file and include that on every page.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this functinality in your code**

```
window.top
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I assume you're suggesting that I place the part of code that that instantiates the popup window in all my website pages and than invoke that function from the child <iframe>, correct? This would have evident disadvantages in terms of maintenance, as every time I'd need to edit that piece of code, I'd have to edit all my website pages. I don't want that.